# thread execution with no synchronization

Tags: multithreading

Threads 1 and 2 are executing concurrently with shared integer variables A, B, and C. 
Thread 1 executes:`A=4, B=5, C=B-A`; Thread 2 executes: `A=3, B=6, C=A+B`;

Suppose there no synchronization implemented. What are all possible values of C after the execution of this fragment?

I know if there is no synchronization then the reads see writes that occur later in the execution order and it will be counter intuitive ( execution will be happens-before consistency)

I am confused what can be the possible values of C.

Comment: The results is undefined. It could be anything. And I mean really anything.

Comment: `if there is no synchronization then the reads see writes that occur later in the execution order` nope not really. There is still an order of execution and the 'reads' can't predict the future.

Comment: Actually why guessing? Write a small spike that has two threads where both increments a shared unprotected variable and then print it to std::cout (each thread should print it). You will see that the threads will really really break the var quickly.

Comment: Can the possible values for C be 1,2,3,8,9,10 after substituting the all possible values  for A & B from both thread 1 and thread 2 for C=B-A & C=A+B